# Как организовать включение функции встраиваемого скрипта в сайт?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Здравствуйте.

Есть скрипт который встраивается в сторонние сайты некоторые функции этого скрипта хочется чтобы пользователь включал и выключал на уровне своего кабинета.

Допустим нажал выключить функцию, и в скрипте она уже как неработающая ставится.

Как понимаю надо во время загрузки скрипта делать запрос к сервер, который будет выдавать данные о включенных функциях например через json.

пробовал так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    functionOn();
});

function functionOn(){ 

            $.ajax({
                    type: "post", url: ""+HOST+"api/function/", data: "id_p=" + window.ProjectId + "", dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.succes == 1){
                            var vk = data.vk;
                        } else {
                            var vk = 0;
                        }
                    }
            });         

}

if (vk == 1) {
... большая функция ...
}
```

Только проблема почему-то не работает, может что-то сделал не правильно, подскажите:

**Как лучше всего сделать правильнее?**

Answer (score 1):

Можно так поправить. Сначала всё определить, потом вызывать.

```
(function(w,$){
    var App = w.App || {};

    App.functionOn = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:   "get", // GET запрос чуть-чуть быстрее, чем POST, а ваши данные влезают в GET.
            url:    "" + HOST + "api/function/",
            data:   {
                id_p: w.ProjectId
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: App.onResponse.bind(this)
        });
    };

    App.onResponse = function(data) {
        if (!data.success  ||  data.success != 1  ||  !data.vk) {
            App.vk = null;
            return; // ф-я отключена
        }

        this.vk = data.vk;

        /*
         * Здесь идёт вызов Большой Адронной Функции
         */
    }

    w.App = App;

})(window,jQuery);

// Инициализация
$(document).ready(function() {
    App.functionOn();
});
```

Возможно, у вас была опечатка. В этом коде ожидается параметр `success` с двумя "s" на конце.

Comment: у вас вижу jQuery, вот хотелось бы без него как-то =/

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev как и в вашем исходном коде. В любом случае, упражнение переписать этот код на чистом JS будет вам полезно, не пожалеете.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то у тебя происходит следующее: сначала инициализируется (и начинает выполнятся) скрипт, а затем (Аяксу нужно время прососаться) у тебя переменной присваивается нужное значение.

Тут 3 варианта:

1) Отложенная инициализация скриптов (все скрипты, кроме данной функции, находятся в пассивном состоянии (т.е. загружаются переменные и функции, но ни одна функция не запускается) и начинают выполнятся только после запуска некоей функции `init();` ( `var init = function(){/*Начинают выполняться действия*/}` ), которую, соответственно, запускаешь уже из `success: function(data){}` после получения всех переменных

```
        [...]
          success: function(data){ 
                        var vk = (data.succes == 1) ? data.vk : 0; 

                       init();
         }
```

2) Скрипт-предзагрузчик

Сначала грузится скрипт с Аяксом, он получает переменные и затем уже подгружает основной скрипт

```
        [...]
        success: function(data){ 
                        var vk = (data.succes == 1) ? data.vk : 0; 
                        /*Подключаем скрипт*/
                        var el = document.createElement('script');
                         el.src = 'http://example.ru/script.js'; //url твоего скрипта 
                        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el); 
         }
```

3) Просто отдавать php-файл (или что там у тебя, если не php) со js-скриптами вместо статичного js-файла - все действия, таким образом, производя прям непосредственно в нем, без лишних Аякс-запросов:

```
 var vk = <?php echo $vk_par; ?>;
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы бы вывод вашего пост-запроса хотя-бы приложили бы. И еще, я бы помимо сервера настройки хранил в тех же кукисах

`var vk = data.vk;` вы объявили переменную внутри метода, следовательно, она не видима за его пределами.

объявите ее до метода и все должно заработать, если output верный

Comment: $json_output = array('succes'=>1, 'vk'=>''.$myrow['vk'].''); вот так json делаю на файле php. Поставить как понял var vk = data.vk; перед $.ajax?

Comment: нет, поставьте var vk = {}; перед function functionOn()